# Not sure why i'm getting a classCastException

Tags: clojure, classcastexception

I am trying to sort the max in lists using this recursion. Unsure why I am getting a class cast exception when trying to call maxOf2.

[image: Code]

Comment: Please paste in your code instead of using an image.

Comment: You should also include the actual exception you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many spacing errors, which is probably the problem.  Also, too many extra parenthesis like `(maxOf2(firstVal ...`  should probably be:

```
(maxOf2 firstVal (listMax (rest aList)))   ; ***** notice spacing! *****
```

Please also consult [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) for more resources.

Comment: That fixed the problem thank you so much! I am very new to Clojure and have been struggling, spacing definitely makes it much easier to read.